# Downloading and extracting zip files with RestKit 0.20.x

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, download, restkit-0.20

I am upgrading my project from RestKit 0.10 to 0.20.2. Successfully done.
Now i need to download a zip file from URL and extract it. I could not find any method in RestKit to do so. Can any one know about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restkit 0.2 uses AFNetworking. Once you configure Restkit in your project, you also have AFNetworking available. Thus, you can download the file like this:

```
- (void)downloadWithOutputPath:(NSString *)aPath progress:(void(^)(NSUInteger, long long , long long ))onProgress success:(void (^)(id<Attachment>))onSuccess error:(void (^)(NSError *))onError
{

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self.client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                                                            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:aPath];
                                                                            NSError *error;
                                                                            [self skipBackupForURL:url error:&error];
                                                                            onSuccess(self);

                                                                        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                            onError(error);
                                                                        }];
    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:onProgress];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:aPath
                                                               append:NO];
    [operation start];
}
```

Also note, that you must mark the downloaded files as excluded from backup.

```
- (void)skipBackupForURL:(NSURL *)anURL error:(NSError **)anError
{
    [anURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                             forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:anError];
}
```

For unzipping files, we use https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive

Comment: Thanks @serrrgi, its really working, just wanted now, which backup you are talking about, the back that iTunes creates?

Comment: Also it caches the file. If i again send request for download, it download from cache. How can i remove cache or force it to download again from web server?

Answer (score 2):

From the RestKit : [Reskit link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)

"RestKit provides a powerful object mapping engine that seamlessly integrates with Core Data and a simple set of networking primitives for mapping HTTP requests and responses built on top of AFNetworking."

For the downloading you can use AFNetworking [AFNetworking link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
For unzipping you can use zipArchive witch is excellent. [zipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)